# Crop and OCR label from photo

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I need to OCR some specific information from labels which are mostly of known layouts. The source of the data is photos which I know can be tricky. The data can be barcodes (easy), short text (mostly known words which can be learned over time as they repeat) and numbers (set format and length).

I've done some research and it seems that Tesseract can do what I want on multiple platforms but I have a few questions.

1) How do I crop only the relevant label. I did some very basic signal processing for a university course a long time ago. I suppose this isn't too difficult. Any good libraries for it?

2) Since I know the layout, is there a way to OCR the labels by section for each specific 
value needed?

3) Any other tips on pre-processing the pictures?

4) Is Tesseract the right tool for the job?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't deal with Tesseract before. However, we use a different third-party toolkit named leadtools. This toolkit can recognized barcodes, text and numbers, and then saves the result on a document format. It can do your requirements since it provides methods to draw a specific zone around the text you want to recognize, and it has some methods for pre-processing the images.
Also, it provides the ability to automatically find the zones in the file you want to OCR. For more information, you can check this [Tutorial](http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/to/leadtools.topics.forms.ocr~fo.topics.ocrtutorialaddingandpaintingzones.html)

Comment: You should mention that leadtools is not free or make a disclosure if you are working for them